# Why Facebook does not show og:video?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-debugger

Here is the url: https://tikex-dev.com/palferi/program/tanciskola

Facebook Debugger does not raise any error.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Mutass egy mozdulatot és játssz az ajándékért!">
<meta property="og:description" content="Szólóban vagy párban? Stúdióban vagy szabadban? Hobbiból vagy versenyszinten? Te hogyan szeretsz táncolni? Oszd meg egyetlen mozdulatban! :-)">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://tikex.com/logo.svg">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/7dum">
<meta property="og:video" content="https://t44-post-cover.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/7dum">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:type" content="movie">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="402670860613108">
```

I see this:

[image]

I tried to share it as a raw mp4 video I put in the public folder:

https://tikex-dev.com/black-and-orang-photography-travelling.mp4

But it is also not loaded into Facebook.

Why?

Comment: Why do you set video:type to application/x-shockwave-flash? Your video is an mp4 and not flash.

Comment: ok, now `video/mp4` is sent, I found `application/x-shockwave-flash` somewhere, anyway `video/mp4` is also not working, but you know what is the strange, I have a direct link to an mp4, and I can not share those either https://tikex-dev.com/black-and-orang-photography-travelling.mp4

Comment: AFAIK, Facebook has stopped playing external videos inline in the news feed a long time ago.